# no red notification when receive message

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I did not receive the small red notification when my friends replied me in the Facebook Chat. Have missed out a few replies due to this issue. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

Can you see the messages? If you can, click on the gear icon on the top right corner. If the "Unmute conversation" option is available (as opposed to the "Mute conversation" option), that's probably it. Just click on it; that should solve the problem.

[image]

If you can't see the messages, perhaps they've been sent to the "Others" folder: I missed a couple of messages this way. If they are in the "Others" folder, you can move them to the Inbox, although I don't know if this will prevent future messages from the same person to be directed to the "Others" folder.

[image]